# Spawn thread from servlet?

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets, spawn

I have a servlet, that calls a web service, and gets data to populate the servlet response.
I also don't want to wait too long.
Can I just spawn a new thread and call the web service? If this is not recommended, what is a better way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Anything can be done.

If you spawn a new thread, that means that you'll have to return something immediately to the client.  What will it be?  Your user will eventually want to know when the data is available.  What's the callback mechanism for letting them know?  Will they poll for it?  Are you going to send a message?  Is there a Fedex-like tracking ID that they can use to find out when the data's ready?

How many threads do you think you'll need?  Will you pool those threads?  What happens if a data request fails?

It's complicated, much more so than a "create a new thread" up or down would imply.  Think it all the way through.

Comment: I want to wait let's say 10 seconds. If the web service doesn't respond, I want to send a servlet resopnse "web service unavail", otherwise I want to compose the servlet response based on what I got from the web service.

Comment: What web service client library are you using? It will probably have some way to define timeouts.

Comment: Thanks Esko, actually I inherited this, but looks like com.ibm.websphere.webservices.http.connectionTimeout will work.

Comment: You'll have a web client wait ten seconds for a response?  You won't have users for long.

Comment: subscribers will have 180 secs :-)  (OK, It was just an example)

Comment: Wow - three minutes.  Good luck.

Comment: @jimnorton: Are you saying if the data doesn't come back fast enough, you just want to cancel the request? That's what will happen if you set a connection timeout.